# Using "crontab -e"

Tags: cron

I'm trying to learn a little about `cron`.

I edited `crontab -e` to have this line:

```
 */10 * * * * /usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/test.txt
```

It works and I see `test.txt` changing its "Date Modified" value every ten min in Thunar and there are corresponding entries in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 13 10:50:01 dkb-lappy CRON[3978]: (dkb) CMD (/usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/test.txt)
Mar 13 11:00:01 dkb-lappy CRON[4066]: (dkb) CMD (/usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/test.txt)
Mar 13 11:10:01 dkb-lappy CRON[4099]: (dkb) CMD (/usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/test.txt)
```

But, if I use

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/$(date +%H:%M:%S).txt
```

**no** file is created at all in ~/Desktop and `syslog` has this:

```
Mar 13 11:30:01 dkb-lappy CRON[4241]: (dkb) CMD (/usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/$(date +)
Mar 13 11:30:01 dkb-lappy CRON[4240]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Mar 13 11:40:01 dkb-lappy CRON[4251]: (dkb) CMD (/usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/$(date +)
Mar 13 11:40:01 dkb-lappy CRON[4250]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I checked that `/usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/$(date +%H:%M:%S).txt` works properly in the terminal.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crontab` treats `%` specially.  You need to escape it with a backslash.

From `man 5 crontab`:

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash  (`\`),
>   will  be  changed  into  newline  characters, and all data after the
>   first % will be sent to the  command as standard input.

Thus, to get `date` to work properly:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/touch /home/dkb/Desktop/$(date +\%H:\%M:\%S).txt
```